# In MongoDB, can hashed shard keys improve query isolation on range queries?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

In Mongo docs, it says that

> MongoDB automatically computes the hashes when resolving queries using
>   hashed indexes. Applications do not need to compute hashes.

From here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/

My common sense tells me that this can only be valid for EQUALS queries.
Is this also valid for range queries? As hashing does not maintain order, I suppose not.

Example:
Say I have a hashed shard key on field *k*.
Definitely, it can help isolate a query like `{k : 111}`.
Can it also help isolate a query like `{k : {'$gt' : 111}}` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the 3rd paragraph here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-hashed/

`Hashed indexes do not support range queries.`

Sorry - it can be frustrating, for sure.

Comment: Can one infer that this extends to hashed sharding keys and query isolation on sharded collections? That's what my question was about. Indeed, my common sense tells me that it also applies, but I didn't find any documented confirmation so far.

Comment: Ah, I did not finish reading, apparently!  This should be testable using the .explain() method on a query, which will show you an explain plan including any indices used and whether it was index-only.  Sometimes it will try it multiple ways and tell you the fastest, other times it won't (like when it can't use it).  You can even provide hints to tell it to use an index and see how that goes.

But, this will not help with your isolation, because it can't.  The index is not storing the value, only the hash of the value, and since that is uniformly distributed it won't provide comparison.